# django.db.utils.IntegrityError "error makemigrations"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'biblioteka_book' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: biblioteka_book.info_id contains a value '1' that does not ha ve a corresponding value in biblioteka_extrainfo.id.

```js
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ExtraInfo(models.Model):
    OCENY = {
        (0, 'Nieznany'),
        (1, 'Słaba'),
        (2, 'Średnia'),
        (3, 'Dobra'),
        (4, 'Bardzo dobra'),
        (5, 'Arcydzieło')
    }
    ilosc_stron = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ocena = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=OCENY)


class Book(models.Model):
    nazwa = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    opis = models.TextField()
    gatunek = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cena = models.DecimalField(max_digits=400, decimal_places=2)
    wydanie = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    autor = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    zdjecie = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=False, upload_to='Pictures')
    przecena = models.BooleanField()
    info = models.OneToOneField(ExtraInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nazwa_with_wydanie()

    def nazwa_with_wydanie(self):
        return str(self.nazwa) + " (" + str(self.wydanie) + ")"
```

Comment: That error message says everything:  `The row in table 'biblioteka_book' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: biblioteka_book.info_id contains a value '1' that does not ha ve a corresponding value in biblioteka_extrainfo.id`.

Comment: I am fresh in these matters so I don't know what to change in my code:
Primary key is True, changing to false gives nothing

Comment: I recommend you to read more about Primary Keys and Foreign Keys in databases., changing Primary Keys on tables in a production server can be catastrophic. I suppose you're doing this on your test machine. If the data in your database is not important, I suggest you delete it (delete the file if you're using sqlite, or drop database if you're using another db) and then run your project again after designing your database and choosing your Primary Key. Consider that Primary Key is a/combination of fields that must be unique in all of your records in database. Also

Comment: Also note that Foreign Keys are some field that refer to a field in another table (=Model in Django). As a conclusion, your Error message says that in Book table, you referred to a ExtraInfo record (with id=1), while there isn't such record in that table. This is not a programmimg error. This caused by some inconsistencies happened in your database because of possibly changing Primary Key.